# Android WifiInfo.getBSSID() returning null, even when connected

Tags: android, wifi

We have an app that scans for available wifi networks. We've received reports that the app is recording Wifi entries that have a null BSSID despite the supplicant state being "COMPLETED"

i.e.

```
WifiInfo info = mWifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
String BSSID = info.getBSSID();
SupplicantState state = info.getSupplicantState();
```

Where BSSID here is null, but the supplicant state is COMPLETED

The documentation states that BSSID is null if no network is available:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiInfo.html#getBSSID()

while the supplicant state is defined thus:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/SupplicantState.html

Unless I am mistaken in my understanding, if the device has connected to a wifi network, surely the BSSID should be available? Why would the BSSID be null if supplicant state is COMPLETED?

edited: for clarity, I don't really care about guaranteeing that the BSSID isn't null, that isn't the point of my question. We are gathering data for broad analysis and if the BSSID is null, so be it, but where the confusion lies is that it is null despite the supplicant being completed. I am genuinely not sure how these two results are reconciled. For further information, we have ensured we have wifi permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

we have NOT given permission, by way of omission, to network state:

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"
    android:required="true" />
```

The ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE is NOT in our manifest.

Could it be, then, that if the user has connected to a mobile network (3G say), then the supplicant state would return COMPLETED, but because we lack permission, we wouldn't be able to get the BSSID?

Answer (score 0):

Check the internet connection before get the BSSID like this:

```
if(checkInternet()){
    WifiInfo info = mWifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
    String BSSID = info.getBSSID();
    SupplicantState state = info.getSupplicantState();
}


public Boolean checkInternet() {
    if (checkWifi()) return true;
    if (checkMobile()) return true;
    ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (connManager.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null) if (connManager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) return true;
    return false;
}

public Boolean checkWifi() {
    ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo mWifi = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
    if (mWifi != null) if (mWifi.isConnected()) return true;
    return false;
}

public Boolean checkMobile() {
    ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo mMobile = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
    if (mMobile != null) if (mMobile.isConnected()) return true;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't answer my question. I want to record data regardless of what the data is, I simply want to know why this discrepancy exists. It doesn't make sense to me that the supplicant state would be COMPLETED but the BSSID would be null, as presumably it if supplicant state is COMPLETED then BSSID would be present. If my understanding is wrong, please by all means correct me.

Answer (score 0):

Which context do you use in `getSystemService` ? Ensure it is active or try to use application context. And check permissions in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"
    android:required="true" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"
    android:required="true" />
```

After that, the below code works in most cases.

```
final WifiManager mWifiManager = (WifiManager) applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
final WifiInfo mWifiInfo = mWifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
    if(mWifiInfo==null){
        return "";
    }
return mWifiInfo.getBSSID();
```

Comment: I've noted that we are missing the ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE permission. Would this explain the discrepancy in my question? If I do not have permission to access the network state, why would BSSID be null but I can still gather the supplicant state?